# How to access child ref from parent

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2

I have dynamic fields need to be validated. The dynamic fields are created using components and can be added into an array with a button. When I tried to validate the dynamic fields, the ref was not found.

**Child Component**

```
<template>
   <el-form :model="dist"
     ref="dynamicForm"
     :rules="rules">...</el-form>
</template>
```

**Parent**

```
<template>
 <el-form :model="dist"
         ref="parentForm"
         :rules="rules">

   <dynamicField
      v-for="df in items></dynamicField>

 </el-form>
</template>

<script>
this.$refs.dynamicForm.validate( (valid) => {
  console.log("Dynamic form validated? " + valid);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Vue.nextTick` for that so `Vue` get enough time to bind reference with `vm`

```
....
methods:{
    clicked(){
      var vm = this      
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
         this.$refs.dynamicForm.validate( (valid) => {
             console.log("Dynamic form validated? " + valid);
         })
      })
    },
}
....
```

also I find some thing in code.

you are using

```
this.$refs.dynamicForm
```

inside parent `instance` and defining it in child `ref="dynamicForm"` not sure its what you want but i guess `refs` cant be accessed over parent child(i guess i didn't check it)

but just for hint may be it can also causing trouble.

> **Update**

**Access Child refs:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child',    
  data: function() {
    return {
      childValue: 'Child Comp ' + Math.ceil((Math.random() * 100))
    }
  },  
  created: function() {    
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    
  },
  created: function() {
    this.refIndex = 0;
  },
  methods: {
     getRef() {
        this.refIndex++;
        return 'childComp' + this.refIndex;
     },
     clickHandler: function() {  
         for(var i=1; i <= this.refIndex; i++ ) {
            console.log(this.$refs['childComp' + i]
                 .$refs.inputOfChild.value);       
         }
     // this.$refs['childComp' + i] -> point to child compo
     // this.$refs['childComp' + i].$refs -> point to child compo's ref
     // this.$refs['childComp' + i].$refs.inputOfChild -> point to child compo's ref's input
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="clickHandler">Access Child's Ref</button><br/>
  <child :ref="getRef()" ></child><br/>
  <child :ref="getRef()" ></child><br/>
  <child :ref="getRef()" ></child><br/>
  <child :ref="getRef()" ></child><br/>
</div>

<template id="child">
   <input ref="inputOfChild" type="text" v-model="childValue">
</template>
```

Comment: My `this.$refs.dynamicForm.validate` method is undefined on parent because `this.$refs.dynamicForm` is undefined.

Comment: How about multiple `<child ref="childComp" ></child>` ?

Answer (score 2):

For access to refs in the child component i use something like this:

```html
...
<Parent>
  <Child ref="child" />
</Parent>
...
```

Method in the parent component:

```
...
onSubmit() {
  let form = this.$refs.child.$refs.form;
  
  if (!form.validate()) {
    return;
  }
}
...
```